Why is my sum of squares of molecular orbital coefficients not 1.0?
I was hoping the sum of squares of molecular orbital coefficients to be 1.0, but alas this is not the case. The occupancy of these orbitals is given as 2.0 . These coefficients were output by both orca_2json and orca_2mkl -molden. What is amiss with what I was expecting?
I am assuming that the sum of squares of mo coeffs equaling 1.0 expectation still holds for localized mos (%loc LocMet IAOIBO).
import pathlib as pl
import numpy as np
import json

ibofn = '/home/grn/qm/7935/1/5/7935_1_5.ibo.json'
ibopath = pl.Path(ibofn)
if not ibopath.is_file():
  print(f'   ibofn is not file {ibofn}\n')
  sys.exit()
with ibopath.open(mode='r') as ibofile:
ibodict = json.load(ibofile)

mos = ibodict['Molecule']['MolecularOrbitals']['MOs']
print(f'count mos={len(mos)}')
for mo in mos:
  occ = mo['Occupancy']
  if occ > 1.0:          # separates occ 2.0 from 0.0
    moc = np.array(mo['MOCoefficients'])
    mocsq = np.square(moc)
    mocsqsum = np.sum(mocsq)
    print(f'sum of squares={mocsqsum:.6f} mo len={len(moc)} occ={occ:.6f}')

Gives output:
count mos=198
sum of squares=0.625267 mo len=198 occ=2.000000
sum of squares=0.624840 mo len=198 occ=2.000000
sum of squares=0.626311 mo len=198 occ=2.000000
sum of squares=0.646868 mo len=198 occ=2.000000
sum of squares=0.557942 mo len=198 occ=2.000000
sum of squares=0.632580 mo len=198 occ=2.000000
sum of squares=0.626151 mo len=198 occ=2.000000
sum of squares=0.624997 mo len=198 occ=2.000000
sum of squares=0.393334 mo len=198 occ=2.000000
sum of squares=0.435620 mo len=198 occ=2.000000
sum of squares=0.636481 mo len=198 occ=2.000000
sum of squares=0.478686 mo len=198 occ=2.000000
sum of squares=0.419610 mo len=198 occ=2.000000
sum of squares=0.367044 mo len=198 occ=2.000000
sum of squares=0.395272 mo len=198 occ=2.000000
sum of squares=0.403178 mo len=198 occ=2.000000
sum of squares=0.371249 mo len=198 occ=2.000000
sum of squares=0.381249 mo len=198 occ=2.000000
sum of squares=0.507786 mo len=198 occ=2.000000
sum of squares=0.447812 mo len=198 occ=2.000000
sum of squares=0.445209 mo len=198 occ=2.000000
sum of squares=0.407671 mo len=198 occ=2.000000
sum of squares=0.408991 mo len=198 occ=2.000000
sum of squares=0.383494 mo len=198 occ=2.000000
sum of squares=0.397010 mo len=198 occ=2.000000
sum of squares=0.391209 mo len=198 occ=2.000000
sum of squares=0.371924 mo len=198 occ=2.000000
sum of squares=0.373078 mo len=198 occ=2.000000


So how much are the sum of squares of molecular orbital coefficients that you calculated?

wzkchem5, I have edited the opening question to supply the data requested.

ORCA's molecular orbital coefficients are given in the AO basis, which is a non-orthogonal basis. In this case you have $C^T SC = I$, not $C^T C = I$. The property that MO coefficients' squares sum to 1 only holds if $C^T C = I$, i.e. only when they are expressed in an orthogonal basis. To do the same thing for the AO basis, you have to read the overlap matrix $S$ as well and calculate a diagonal element of $C^T SC$, and check whether that is equal to 1.

Exactly 1.0 on the diagonal, 10^-16 or less for off-diagonal elements.
